# How to Write a Custom Rule Function for Quantstrat in R - Replace trailing stop order with stoplimit with ruleOrderProc

Tags: r, trading, algorithmic-trading, quantstrat, blotter

**My goal is to use the rule that I outline below to generate a signal to place a new 'stoplimit' order that replaces my trailing stop.** I don't want my stop to trail indefinitely, only until it reaches my breakeven price (if this can be achieved somehow already, please let me know).

**I am hoping to write a custom rule in quantstrat with the following objective:**

If today's "Close" minus (-) the threshold value (a scalar) on the timestamp of trade open, is greater than (>) the "Open" price on timestamp of trade open (this is also the fill value or order.price) THEN generate a trade (I'd also only like for this to occur one time so something like cross = T)

```
For example:
Open a Trade on 01-01-2000 @ $150.00
Threshold value on 01-01-2000 is $5.00
Today's Close on 02-01-2000  = "$155.50"
```

Since today's close minus the threshold is > fill price, generate a signal to place an order. The issue is I don't think this can be done with add.signal, at least not outside of the add.rule function because *I need access to the order book*. I can't pre-calculate on the mktdata object because I have many entry signals that do not generate orders, and looking at mktdata alone, there is no way to tell which signals resulted in an order.

**Could someone advise me what part of add.rule() I need to adapt to make this possible? If I need to write my own `ruleSignal` function, what do I put for sigcol and sigval since I have no signal ahead of time?**

Here are my current rules for a long trade:

```
# Long Entry
add.rule(strategy.st, name = 'ruleSignal',
     arguments = list(sigcol = 'longSig',
                      sigval = TRUE,
                      replace = F,
                      orderside = 'long',
                      ordertype = 'market',
                      osFUN     = osATR,
                      prefer    = 'Open'),
                      type      = 'enter',
                      label     = 'enterLong',
                      path.dep  = T)


# Long Stop
add.rule(strategy.st, name = 'ruleSignal',
     arguments = list(sigcol = 'longSig', sigval = T,
                      orderqty = 'all', ordertype = 'stoptrailing',
                      orderside = 'long',
                      replace   = F,
                      threshold = 'stpVal'),
                      orderset = 'goLong',
                      type = 'chain',
                      path.dep = T,
                      parent = 'enterLong')
```

Any help is appreciated and I will share my results. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution of modifying the core `ruleOrderProc` function in quantstrat seems fine.  If you're looking for an out of the box solution to your problem that doesn't require modifying the quantstrat souce code, you could make use of the handy
`"trigger"` order qty argument.  As noted in the quantstrat documentation for the `ruleSignal` found in `ruleSignal.R`:

> \code{orderqty} should be either numeric, or one of 'all'/'trigger'. 'all' can only be used with order of ruletype='exit'
>   or 'risk', and will close the entire position. 'trigger' can only be
>   used with ruletype='chain' and is exactly identical to 'all', except
>   that the actual transaction is suppressed, and can be used to kick in
>   a new order chain.

Here is a self contained simplified strategy that I think does what you want.

Note that if the limit order with the trigger is filled, there is no actual transaction that takes place (look at the source for `ruleOrderProc` and you'll see that `addTxn` doesn't get called if it's a `trigger` quantity).

The instrument is GBPUSD, and the data is from quantstrat. The strategy enters a long position when the MACD signal crosses 0 from below.  If the MACD signal then crosses below 0, any open long positions are exited. If the price increases by more than 0.05% of the price (remember this is an FX rate so smaller percent moves are expected compared to say equities)  at the time of entry, then any open trailing stop will be converted to a stoplimit.

This approach requires defining a new rule function that handles the conversion from the stoptrailing to stoplimit.

```
library(quantstrat)
from <- "2002-10-20"
to <- "2002-10-21"

symbols <- "GBPUSD"
# Load 1 minute data stored in the quantstrat package
getSymbols.FI(Symbols = symbols,
              dir=system.file('extdata',package='quantstrat'),
              from=from, 
              to=to
)

currency(c('GBP', 'USD'))
exchange_rate('GBPUSD', tick_size=0.0001)

strategy.st <- "updateStopStrat"
portfolio.st <- "updateStopStrat"
account.st <- "updateStopStrat"

rm.strat(strategy.st)

initPortf(portfolio.st, symbols = symbols)
initAcct(account.st, portfolios = portfolio.st, initEq = 1e5)
initOrders(portfolio.st)
strategy(strategy.st, store = TRUE)

tradeSize <- 1000
for (sym in symbols) {
  addPosLimit(portfolio.st, sym, start(get(sym)), tradeSize)
}


strategy(strategy.st, store=TRUE)

fastMA = 12 
slowMA = 26 
signalMA = 9
maType = "EMA"
n.RSI <- 30
thresRSI <- 80

add.indicator(strategy.st, name = "MACD", 
              arguments = list(x=quote(Cl(mktdata)),
                               nFast=fastMA, 
                               nSlow=slowMA),
              label='co' 
)

add.signal(strategy.st,name="sigThreshold",
           arguments = list(column="signal.co",
                            relationship="gt",
                            threshold=0,
                            cross=TRUE),
           label="signal.gt.zero"
)


entryThreshold <- 0.0005


add.signal(strategy.st,name="sigThreshold",
           arguments = list(column="signal.co",
                            relationship="lt",
                            threshold=0,
                            cross=TRUE),
           label="signal.lt.zero"
)

# For debugging purposes:
#mdata <- applyIndicators(strategy.st, GBPUSD)
#mdata <- applySignals(strategy.st, mdata)
#stop()

# Define a custom rule to handle converting an "open" stoptrailing order to a stoplimit order.  This will be included as part of a rule:

ruleModify_stoptrailing1 <- function(mktdata = mktdata, 
                                     timestamp, 
                                     sigcol, 
                                     sigval, 
                                     orderqty=0, 
                                     ordertype, 
                                     orderside=NULL, 
                                     orderset=NULL, 
                                     threshold=NULL, 
                                     tmult=FALSE, 
                                     replace=TRUE, 
                                     delay=0.0001, 
                                     osFUN='osNoOp', 
                                     pricemethod=c('market','opside','active'), 
                                     portfolio, 
                                     symbol, 
                                     ..., 
                                     ruletype, 
                                     TxnFees=0, 
                                     prefer=NULL, 
                                     sethold=FALSE, 
                                     label='', 
                                     order.price=NULL, 
                                     chain.price=NULL, 
                                     time.in.force='') {


  orderbook <- getOrderBook(portfolio)
  ordersubset <- orderbook[[portfolio]][[symbol]]

  # Use quantstrat helper function to identify which row in orderbook for this symbol (ordersubset) has the order we want to change:
  ii <- getOrders(portfolio=portfolio, 
                  symbol=symbol, 
                  status="open", 
                  timespan=timespan, 
                  ordertype="stoptrailing", 
                  side = orderside,
                  orderset = orderset,
                  which.i = TRUE)
  if (length(ii) > 0) {
    # If a stoptrailing order is open, then we may turn it into a fixed "hardstop" (stoplimit)

    ordersubset[ii,"Order.Status"] <- 'replaced' 
    ordersubset[ii,"Order.StatusTime"] <- format(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    if (length(ii) != 1) 
      stop("Have not got logic for handling case with more than one open trailing stop on one order side.")

    orderThreshold <- as.numeric(ordersubset[ii, "Order.Threshold"])
    if(hasArg(prefer)) prefer=match.call(expand.dots=TRUE)$prefer
    else prefer = NULL
    neworder <- addOrder(portfolio=portfolio,
                         symbol=symbol,
                         timestamp=timestamp,
                         qty=ordersubset[ii,"Order.Qty"],
                         # add back in the orderThreshold (orderThreshold is
                         # negative), so the Order.Price reported in the order
                         # book is the correct level for the stop.  Put
                         # another way, if you don't subtract the
                         # order.threshold here, the stop price level, given by
                         # Order.Price in the orderbook, won't be set at the
                         # expected level, but rather at the stop level - the value of orderThreshold.
                         price= as.numeric(ordersubset[ii, "Order.Price"]) -
                           orderThreshold,
                         ordertype="stoplimit",
                         prefer=prefer,
                         side=ordersubset[ii,"Order.Side"],
                         # if you dont provide the correct sign of orderThreshold (want negative for long side), addOrder will automagically set the sign appropriately to negative value here for a orderside = "long" stoplimit order.  
                         threshold = orderThreshold,
                         status="open",
                         replace=FALSE, 
                         return=TRUE,
                         orderset=ordersubset[ii,"Order.Set"],
                         label=label,
                         ...=..., 
                         TxnFees=TxnFees)
    # ^ Do not need to set the statustimestamp because any new orders start with statustimestamp = NA.

    ordersubset<-rbind(ordersubset, neworder)

    # we we have updated the orderbook for this symbol, we should reflect this
    # where the orderbook is stored (in the .strategy environment):
    orderbook[[portfolio]][[symbol]] <- ordersubset
    put.orderbook(portfolio, orderbook)
  }
}


add.rule(strategy.st,name='ruleSignal', 
         arguments = list(sigcol="signal.gt.zero",
                          sigval=TRUE, 
                          orderqty=tradeSize, 
                          ordertype='market', 
                          orderside='long', 
                          threshold=NULL),
         type='enter',
         label='enterL',
         storefun=FALSE
)

# convert the stop order when this threshold is achieved:
entryThreshold <- 0.0005

add.rule(strategy.st,name='ruleSignal', 
         arguments = list(sigcol="signal.gt.zero", 
                          sigval=TRUE, 
                          orderqty='trigger', 
                          ordertype='limit', 
                          orderside='long', 
                          threshold=entryThreshold, 
                          # cant be part of the 'sysMACD'orderset, otherwise when this limit order closes, it will cancel the trailingstop in the same orderset, as well as any other potential orders in the 'sysMACD' orderset such as a potential take profit (limit)
                          orderset='sysMACD.augment',
                          tmult=TRUE, 
                          replace = FALSE),
         type='chain', 
         parent='enterL', 
         label='updateStopTrigger')


add.rule(strategy.st,name='ruleSignal', 
         arguments = list(sigcol="signal.lt.zero",
                          sigval=TRUE, 
                          orderqty='all', 
                          ordertype='market', 
                          orderside='long', 
                          threshold=NULL,
                          orderset='sysMACD',
                          replace = TRUE),
         type='exit',
         label='exitL'
)

# Typically stoptrailing order in quantstrat:
add.rule(strategy.st,name='ruleSignal', 
         arguments = list(sigcol="signal.gt.zero", 
                          sigval=TRUE, 
                          orderqty='all', 
                          ordertype='stoptrailing', 
                          orderside='long', 
                          threshold=-entryThreshold, 
                          tmult=TRUE, 
                          orderset='sysMACD',
                          replace = FALSE),
         type='chain', 
         parent='enterL', 
         label='movingStop')




# Make sure to cancel the trigger limit order under all possible scenarios in which the trigger order is not "filled"/closed, which for this strategy are:
# 1) trailing stop in order set sysMACD was closed
# 2) exit order (MACD crosses below 0) in order set sysMACD.augment was closed

# Custom functions to cancel the "open" "updateStopTrigger" order, otherwise this order will remain open while the underlying position was closed from a stop filling, or an exit trade:
ruleCancTriggerStop <- function(portfolio, symbol, timespan, orderside, orderset, timestamp, ...) {

  updateOrders(portfolio=portfolio, 
               symbol=symbol, 
               timespan=timespan,
               side=orderside,
               orderset=orderset, 
               oldstatus='open', 
               newstatus='canceled',
               statustimestamp=timestamp
  )
  return()
}

ruleCancTriggerExit <- function(portfolio, symbol, timespan, orderside, orderset, timestamp, ...) {

  updateOrders(portfolio=portfolio, 
               symbol=symbol, 
               timespan=timespan,
               side=orderside,
               orderset=orderset, 
               oldstatus='open', 
               newstatus='canceled',
               statustimestamp=timestamp
  )
  return()
}


add.rule(strategy.st,name='ruleCancTriggerExit', 
         arguments = list(sigcol="signal.lt.zero",
                          sigval=TRUE, 
                          orderqty='all', 
                          ordertype='chain', 
                          orderside='long', 
                          threshold=NULL,
                          orderset='sysMACD.augment',
                          replace = FALSE),
         parent = "exitL",
         type='chain',
         label='revokeTrig1'
)

add.rule(strategy.st,name='ruleCancTriggerStop', 
         arguments = list(sigcol="signal.lt.zero",
                          sigval=TRUE, 
                          orderqty='all', 
                          ordertype='chain', 
                          orderside='long', 
                          threshold=NULL,
                          orderset='sysMACD.augment',
                          replace = FALSE),
         parent = "movingStop",
         type='chain',
         label='revokeTrig2'
)


# New rule that may convert an open long trailing stop to a stoplimit, if the price increases by more than a certain amount.

add.rule(strategy.st, name = 'ruleModify_stoptrailing1', 
         # sigcol here and sigval don't matter as this rule is activated just when the limit order with label "updateStopTrigger" fills.
         arguments = list(sigcol="signal.gt.zero", 
                          sigval=TRUE, 
                          orderqty='all', 
                          ordertype='stoplimit', 
                          orderside='long', 
                          threshold=-entryThreshold,
                          tmult=TRUE, 
                          orderset='sysMACD',
                          replace = FALSE),
         type = 'chain',  # process and update this order after processing whether the trailing stop was touched, any chain exit and entry orders
         parent = "updateStopTrigger",
         label ='HARDSTOP')
#stop("update applyStrat for not updating stoptrailng.")

out<-applyStrategy(strategy.st, portfolios=portfolio.st, verbose=TRUE)

tx <- getTxns(portfolio.st, "GBPUSD")

sum(tx$Net.Txn.Realized.PL)
# -2.26905

head(tx)
# Txn.Qty Txn.Price Txn.Fees Txn.Value Txn.Avg.Cost Net.Txn.Realized.PL
# 1950-01-01 00:00:00       0  0.000000        0     0.000     0.000000             0.00000
# 2002-10-20 21:31:00    1000  1.547700        0  1547.700     1.547700             0.00000
# 2002-10-20 21:40:00   -1000  1.547326        0 -1547.326     1.547326            -0.37385
# 2002-10-20 22:04:00    1000  1.548200        0  1548.200     1.548200             0.00000
# 2002-10-20 23:07:00   -1000  1.549000        0 -1549.000     1.549000             0.80000
# 2002-10-20 23:39:00    1000  1.548900        0  1548.900     1.548900             0.00000

ob <- getOrderBook(portfolio.st)

# Look at the orderbook and see if things are working as expected:
head(ob[[portfolio.st]]$GBPUSD, 15)
# Order.Qty Order.Price  Order.Type     Order.Side Order.Threshold Order.Status Order.StatusTime      Prefer Order.Set         Txn.Fees Rule                Time.In.Force
# 2002-10-20 21:30:00.00010 "1000"    "1.5478"     "market"       "long"     NA              "closed"     "2002-10-20 21:31:00" ""     NA                "0"      "enterL"            ""           
# 2002-10-20 21:31:00.00010 "trigger" "1.54847385" "limit"        "long"     "0.00077385"    "canceled"   "2002-10-20 21:40:00" ""     "sysMACD.augment" "0"      "updateStopTrigger" ""           
# 2002-10-20 21:31:00.00010 "all"     "1.54692615" "stoptrailing" "long"     "-0.00077385"   "replaced"   "2002-10-20 21:33:00" ""     "sysMACD"         "0"      "movingStop"        ""           
# 2002-10-20 21:33:00.00001 "all"     "1.54702615" "stoptrailing" "long"     "-0.00077385"   "replaced"   "2002-10-20 21:34:00" ""     "sysMACD"         "0"      "movingStop"        ""           
# 2002-10-20 21:34:00.00001 "all"     "1.54732615" "stoptrailing" "long"     "-0.00077385"   "closed"     "2002-10-20 21:40:00" ""     "sysMACD"         "0"      "movingStop"        ""           
# 2002-10-20 22:03:00.00010 "1000"    "1.5482"     "market"       "long"     NA              "closed"     "2002-10-20 22:04:00" ""     NA                "0"      "enterL"            ""           
# 2002-10-20 22:04:00.00010 "trigger" "1.5489741"  "limit"        "long"     "0.0007741"     "closed"     "2002-10-20 22:21:00" ""     "sysMACD.augment" "0"      "updateStopTrigger" ""           
# 2002-10-20 22:04:00.00010 "all"     "1.5474259"  "stoptrailing" "long"     "-0.0007741"    "replaced"   "2002-10-20 22:06:00" ""     "sysMACD"         "0"      "movingStop"        ""           
# 2002-10-20 22:06:00.00001 "all"     "1.5478259"  "stoptrailing" "long"     "-0.0007741"    "replaced"   "2002-10-20 22:20:00" ""     "sysMACD"         "0"      "movingStop"        ""           
# 2002-10-20 22:20:00.00001 "all"     "1.5479259"  "stoptrailing" "long"     "-0.0007741"    "replaced"   "2002-10-20 22:21:00" ""     "sysMACD"         "0"      "movingStop"        ""           
# 2002-10-20 22:21:00.00001 "all"     "1.5482259"  "stoptrailing" "long"     "-0.0007741"    "replaced"   "2002-10-20 22:21:00" ""     "sysMACD"         "0"      "movingStop"        ""           
# 2002-10-20 22:21:00.00001 "all"     "1.5482259"  "stoplimit"    "long"     "-0.0007741"    "replaced"   "2002-10-20 23:06:00" ""     "sysMACD"         "0"      "HARDSTOP"          ""           
# 2002-10-20 23:06:00.00010 "all"     "1.549"      "market"       "long"     NA              "closed"     "2002-10-20 23:07:00" ""     "sysMACD"         "0"      "exitL"             ""           
# 2002-10-20 23:38:00.00010 "1000"    "1.5489"     "market"       "long"     NA              "closed"     "2002-10-20 23:39:00" ""     NA                "0"      "enterL"            ""           
# 2002-10-20 23:39:00.00010 "trigger" "1.54967445" "limit"        "long"     "0.00077445"    "canceled"   "2002-10-20 23:45:00" ""     "sysMACD.augment" "0"      "updateStopTrigger" ""   

# As a check on the strategy logic, let's examine the position opened at 2002-10-20 22:04
# and closed at 2002-10-20 23:07, because we can see the stoptrailing order was
# converted to a stoplimit in the orderbook during the life of this position.

# The stoptrailing converted to a stoplimit at 2002-10-20 22:21:00.

# The transaction price on entry was 1.548200 @ 22:04.   And we expect conversion when the market price reaches
1.548200 * (1 + entryThreshold)
# 1.548974

# Let's look at the market data during this period, and check when the price first touches 1.548974:
mktdata["2002-10-20 22"]

# Open   High    Low  Close Volume     macd.co     signal.co signal.gt.zero signal.lt.zero
# 2002-10-20 22:00:00 1.5480 1.5480 1.5480 1.5480      0 0.001132692 -0.0042646426              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:01:00 1.5480 1.5480 1.5480 1.5480      0 0.003498427 -0.0027120286              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:02:00 1.5479 1.5480 1.5479 1.5480      0 0.005311960 -0.0011072309              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:03:00 1.5482 1.5482 1.5482 1.5482      0 0.007703042  0.0006548237              1              0
# 2002-10-20 22:04:00 1.5481 1.5482 1.5481 1.5482      0 0.009488476  0.0024215542              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:05:00 1.5481 1.5482 1.5481 1.5482      0 0.010779080  0.0040930594              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:06:00 1.5484 1.5486 1.5483 1.5485      0 0.013213351  0.0059171177              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:07:00 1.5486 1.5486 1.5485 1.5485      0 0.014969758  0.0077276458              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:08:00 1.5485 1.5485 1.5485 1.5485      0 0.016175102  0.0094171370              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:09:00 1.5484 1.5484 1.5484 1.5484      0 0.016419726  0.0108176549              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:10:00 1.5483 1.5483 1.5482 1.5483      0 0.015908934  0.0118359108              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:11:00 1.5484 1.5484 1.5483 1.5484      0 0.015842678  0.0126372642              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:12:00 1.5483 1.5484 1.5483 1.5484      0 0.015610180  0.0132318473              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:13:00 1.5484 1.5484 1.5484 1.5484      0 0.015250094  0.0136354967              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:14:00 1.5482 1.5483 1.5482 1.5483      0 0.014278923  0.0137641819              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:15:00 1.5484 1.5484 1.5484 1.5484      0 0.013870539  0.0137854534              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:16:00 1.5484 1.5484 1.5484 1.5484      0 0.013392491  0.0137068610              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:17:00 1.5484 1.5484 1.5484 1.5484      0 0.012865315  0.0135385518              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:18:00 1.5485 1.5485 1.5485 1.5485      0 0.012820874  0.0133950162              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:19:00 1.5485 1.5485 1.5485 1.5485      0 0.012639919  0.0132439967              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:20:00 1.5486 1.5487 1.5486 1.5487      0 0.013384461  0.0132720896              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:21:00 1.5490 1.5490 1.5487 1.5487      0 0.013815191  0.0133807099              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:22:00 1.5487 1.5487 1.5487 1.5487      0 0.013995162  0.0135036003              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:23:00 1.5486 1.5491 1.5486 1.5491      0 0.016037197  0.0140103195              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:24:00 1.5492 1.5494 1.5492 1.5494      0 0.018999415  0.0150081387              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:25:00 1.5496 1.5496 1.5496 1.5496      0 0.022133478  0.0164332065              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:26:00 1.5500 1.5501 1.5500 1.5500      0 0.026396277  0.0184258206              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:27:00 1.5498 1.5498 1.5497 1.5497      0 0.027889711  0.0203185987              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:28:00 1.5495 1.5495 1.5493 1.5493      0 0.026681891  0.0215912573              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:29:00 1.5495 1.5495 1.5494 1.5494      0 0.025946416  0.0224622889              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:30:00 1.5493 1.5493 1.5493 1.5493      0 0.024559503  0.0228817318              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:31:00 1.5492 1.5492 1.5492 1.5492      0 0.022678056  0.0228409967              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:32:00 1.5494 1.5496 1.5493 1.5493      0 0.021460473  0.0225648918              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:33:00 1.5493 1.5493 1.5492 1.5492      0 0.019747018  0.0220013171              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:34:00 1.5491 1.5491 1.5489 1.5490      0 0.017149670  0.0210309877              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:35:00 1.5492 1.5492 1.5491 1.5491      0 0.015434221  0.0199116344              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:36:00 1.5491 1.5491 1.5491 1.5491      0 0.013914325  0.0187121724              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:37:00 1.5490 1.5490 1.5487 1.5489      0 0.011535059  0.0172767497              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:38:00 1.5492 1.5492 1.5492 1.5492      0 0.011084377  0.0160382752              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:39:00 1.5492 1.5492 1.5492 1.5492      0 0.010604952  0.0149516105              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:40:00 1.5496 1.5496 1.5496 1.5496      0 0.012168207  0.0143949299              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:41:00 1.5495 1.5496 1.5495 1.5496      0 0.013254194  0.0141667827              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:42:00 1.5497 1.5497 1.5496 1.5496      0 0.013953900  0.0141242062              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:43:00 1.5495 1.5495 1.5495 1.5495      0 0.013828134  0.0140649917              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:44:00 1.5496 1.5497 1.5495 1.5495      0 0.013571982  0.0139663898              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:45:00 1.5495 1.5495 1.5495 1.5495      0 0.013216603  0.0138164325              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:46:00 1.5495 1.5495 1.5495 1.5495      0 0.012787536  0.0136106532              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:47:00 1.5494 1.5494 1.5492 1.5492      0 0.010761044  0.0130407315              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:48:00 1.5493 1.5493 1.5492 1.5492      0 0.009050703  0.0122427258              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:49:00 1.5494 1.5495 1.5494 1.5495      0 0.009152182  0.0116246171              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:50:00 1.5494 1.5494 1.5494 1.5494      0 0.008612505  0.0110221948              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:51:00 1.5495 1.5495 1.5494 1.5494      0 0.008091531  0.0104360620              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:52:00 1.5494 1.5495 1.5494 1.5494      0 0.007591147  0.0098670789              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:53:00 1.5494 1.5494 1.5494 1.5494      0 0.007112597  0.0093161825              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:54:00 1.5494 1.5494 1.5494 1.5494      0 0.006656609  0.0087842677              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:55:00 1.5492 1.5493 1.5492 1.5492      0 0.005193756  0.0080661654              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:56:00 1.5493 1.5494 1.5493 1.5494      0 0.005018204  0.0074565731              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:57:00 1.5494 1.5494 1.5493 1.5493      0 0.004308602  0.0068269789              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:58:00 1.5494 1.5494 1.5492 1.5492      0 0.003188666  0.0060993163              0              0
# 2002-10-20 22:59:00 1.5493 1.5493 1.5492 1.5492      0 0.002274880  0.0053344290              0              0

# We can see the price first touches 1.5490 on the 2002-10-20 22:21:00 bar, which is the timestamp at which the stoptrailing is closed and the stoplimit is opened in the orderbook.
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a temporary solution by changing the source of `quantstrat::ruleOrderProc`

You can find the master branch here ---> [quantstrat::ruleOrderProc](https://github.com/braverock/quantstrat/blob/b32907739c1aca80cb9a49de79a980e1b9922bc5/R/ruleOrderProc.R)

**A few notes:** *I am using OHLC daily data. This will not work with BBO or tick data. There is also no way to revert to a permanently trailing stop.* My alteration  places a `stoplimit` order whenever my `stoptrailing` order reaches my entry price.

Near line 347 on the github master branch at `347 > elseif(isOHLCmktdata) {`

I made the following changes:

```
           else if(isOHLCmktdata)
           {
             # check to see if price moved through the limit THE IS A "CLOSED" ORDER

             order.side <- ordersubset[ii, "Order.Side"]

             if(order.side == 'long'  && as.numeric(Lo(mktdataTimestamp)[,1]) < orderPrice
                || order.side == 'short' && as.numeric(Hi(mktdataTimestamp)[,1]) > orderPrice)
             {
               txnprice <- orderPrice
               txntime <- timestamp
             }
             else
             {
               # THIS IS WHERE THE TRAILING STOP IS ADJUSTED
               # Get order threshold
               order.threshold <- as.numeric(ordersubset[ii, "Order.Threshold"])
               order.qty <- ordersubset[ii, "Order.Qty"]   # if orderQty='all' we must recover it

               # Get the fill price
               transactions      <- getTxns(Portfolio = portfolio, Symbol = symbol)
               last.transaction  <- tail(transactions, 1)
               trans.price       <- last.transaction[,2]


               if(order.side == 'long')
                 new.order.price <- max(orderPrice, as.numeric(Hi(mktdataTimestamp)[,1]) + order.threshold)
               if(order.side == 'short')
                 new.order.price <- min(orderPrice, as.numeric(Lo(mktdataTimestamp)[,1]) + order.threshold)

               if(new.order.price != orderPrice)
               {
                 if (order.side == 'long' && new.order.price > trans.price || order.side == 'short' && new.order.price < trans.price) {

                   # Add an order with a stoplimit order type
                   neworder<-addOrder(portfolio=portfolio,
                                      symbol=symbol,
                                      timestamp=timestamp,
                                      qty=order.qty,
                                      price=new.order.price - order.threshold,
                                      ordertype='stoplimit',
                                      side=order.side,
                                      threshold=order.threshold,
                                      status="open",
                                      replace=FALSE, return=TRUE,
                                      orderset=ordersubset[ii,"Order.Set"],
                                      label=ordersubset[ii,"Rule"],
                                      ,...=..., TxnFees=txnfees)

                 } else {
                 # adjust trailing stop
                 neworder<-addOrder(portfolio=portfolio,
                                    symbol=symbol,
                                    timestamp=timestamp,
                                    qty=order.qty,
                                    price=new.order.price - order.threshold,
                                    ordertype=orderType,
                                    side=order.side,
                                    threshold=order.threshold,
                                    status="open",
                                    replace=FALSE, return=TRUE,
                                    orderset=ordersubset[ii,"Order.Set"],
                                    label=ordersubset[ii,"Rule"],
                                    ,...=..., TxnFees=txnfees)
                 }

                 ordersubset<-rbind(ordersubset, neworder)

                 ordersubset[ii,"Order.Status"]<-'replaced'
                 ordersubset[ii,"Order.StatusTime"]<-format(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

                 next()
               }
             }
           }

         } # end stoptrailing
```

The major change is getting the fill price

```
    # Get the fill price
           transactions      <- getTxns(Portfolio = portfolio, Symbol = symbol)
           last.transaction  <- tail(transactions, 1)
           trans.price       <- last.transaction[,2]
```

and then adding this `if` statement

```
    if (order.side == 'long' && new.order.price > trans.price || order.side == 'short' && new.order.price < trans.price) {
```

to place a `stoplimit` order instead of moving the stop indefinitely. So far it has been working properly.