# Quantstrat: Updating prices for multiple limit orders (entry + exit)

Tags: r, quantstrat

I'm trying to implement a strategy that updates limit orders on every bar. The strategy will always open a new position when closing an old position, so I always need an exit order as well as an entry order on the books.

If I use `replace=T`, my exit order erases my entry order, which means it would take two bars to change positions instead of one. If I use `replace=F`, then it keeps *adding* orders, leaving old orders unchanged. Neither is the behavior I'm looking for.

Is there a way to modify open orders by label? For example, change price for both my limit order labeled `ShortExit` as well as my limit order labeled `LongEntry`?

```
require(quantstrat)

stock.str='IBM' # what are we trying it on

currency('USD')
stock(stock.str,currency='USD',multiplier=1)

startDate='2006-12-31'
initEq=1000000

strat.st<-portfolio.st <-account.st <- 'bbands'
rm.strat(portfolio.st)
rm.strat(account.st)
strategy(strat.st, store=TRUE)
initPortf(portfolio.st, symbols=stock.str)
initAcct(account.st,portfolios='bbands')
initOrders(portfolio=portfolio.st)
addPosLimit(portfolio.st, stock.str, startDate, 100, 1 ) #set max pos


kchannel <- function(HLC,n){
  center <- SMA(Cl(HLC),n)
  atr <- ATR(HLC,n)$atr
  up <- center + 2*atr
  dn <- center - 2*atr
  mom <- momentum(center)
  out <- merge(center,atr,up,dn,mom)
  colnames(out) <- c("center","atr","up","dn","mom")
  return(out)
}

add.indicator(strategy = strat.st, 
              name = "kchannel", 
              arguments = list(HLC = quote(HLC(mktdata)), 
                               n=n
              ), 
              label='kc')

add.signal(strategy = strat.st,
           name="sigThreshold",
           arguments = list(column="mom.kc",
                            thresh=0,
                            relationship="gt"),
           label="long")

add.signal(strategy = strat.st,
           name="sigThreshold",
           arguments = list(column="mom.kc",
                            thresh=0,
                            relationship="lt"),
           label="short")

add.rule(strategy = strat.st,name='ruleSignal',
         arguments = list(sigcol="long",
                          sigval=TRUE,
                          orderqty=200,
                          orderside="long",
                          replace=T,
                          ordertype='limit',
                          prefer="dn",
                          osFUN=osMaxPos),
         type='enter',
         label="LongEntry")

add.rule(strategy = strat.st,name='ruleSignal',
         arguments = list(sigcol="short",
                          sigval=TRUE,
                          orderqty=-200,
                          orderside="short",
                          replace=T,
                          ordertype='limit',
                          prefer="up",
                          osFUN=osMaxPos),
         type='enter',
         label="ShortEntry")

add.rule(strategy = strat.st,name='ruleSignal',
         arguments = list(sigcol="short",
                          sigval=TRUE,
                          orderqty="all",
                          orderside="long",
                          replace=T,
                          ordertype='limit',
                          prefer="dn",
                          osFUN=osMaxPos),
         type='exit',
         label="LongExit")

add.rule(strategy = strat.st,name='ruleSignal',
         arguments = list(sigcol="long",
                          sigval=TRUE,
                          orderqty="all",
                          orderside="short",
                          replace=T,
                          ordertype='limit',
                          prefer="up",
                          osFUN=osMaxPos),
         type='exit',
         label="ShortExit")


getSymbols(stock.str,from=startDate,index.class=c('POSIXt','POSIXct'), src='yahoo')
start_t<-Sys.time()
out<-try(applyStrategy(strategy='bbands' , portfolios='bbands') )
updatePortf(Portfolio='bbands')

chart.Posn(Portfolio='bbands',Symbol=stock.str)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more clearly what you want to do?  The short answer is no you can't update the limit order prices without cancelling them and posting new limit orders with new prices.  You might find `orderqty = trigger` useful in what you're trying to do.  I gave an example here, that might help you toward what you want to do:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49069038/how-to-write-a-custom-rule-function-for-quantstrat-in-r-replace-trailing-stop/50370072#50370072